# Question about the Cameron-Martin-Girsanov (CMG) theorem

Tags: brownian-motion, risk-neutral-measure, girsanov

Within my lecture notes, the following definition of the CMG theorem is given:

> Under the probability measure $\mathbb{\tilde{P}}$ with density $\gamma_T = \exp(cW_T - \frac{c^2}{2}T)$, the process $W_t$, $0 \leq t \leq T$ is a Wiener process with drift $+ct$, while the process
>   $$
> \tilde{W}_t := W_t - ct \hspace{10mm} (*)
> $$
>   is a new Wiener process.

My question is, should $(*)$ not be
$$
\tilde{W}_t := W_t \mathbb{+} ct
$$
since we are talking about a new Wiener process with drift $\mathbb{+} ct$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to CMG theorem, if $W_t$ is a Wiener process under the old measure, then under the new measure $\tilde{W_t}$ is a Wiener process, where:
$$\tilde{W_t} = W_t + \langle cW, W \rangle_t = W_t - ct$$

Both statements express this same idea:

- Moving from the old measure to new one adds a drift $ct$, so if you take a Wiener process (under the old measure) and express it under the new measure, you will get a Wiener process with a drift term $ct$.
- So, if you want to get back to a Wiener process (i.e. drift = 0) under the new measure, then you have to remove this $ct$ term.